# JQuery use value for location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to I use a JQuery value for a url to use with location.href?

The url will be different every time the below url is an example.

The URL is stored in the database as

> audit.php?audit=13957911461655047299&page=summary

Ajax is then used to retrieve the URL and save in a var called last_viewed so I would like to use the equivalent of

```
location.href = last_viewed
```

I have tried

```
location.href = '"'+last_viewed+'"'
```

but the URL becomes

> http://www.x-rayqa.co.uk/"audit.php?audit=13957911461655047299&page=summary"

which obviously won't work because of the extra "s

if I try just

```
 location.href = last_viewed
```

nothing happens, the script is broken.

Comment: var url = "audit.php?audit=13957911461655047299&page=summary";
location.href = url;

This redirects me to "www.testtesttest.com/audit.php?audit=13957911461655047299&page=summary", which I guess is what you want. In other words, your last example should work if last_viewed is of the correct value.

Comment: Have you tried window.location.href = last_viewed?

Comment: @DanielHallqvist the url is different every time, the one given in the  question is an example to demonstrate the format of the url.  I have edited the question to make this clearer

Comment: well then try `location.href = '' + last_viewed+ '';`, without the `"`?

Comment: @xFortyFourx thanks but breaks the script, nothing happens

Comment: You might wanna show the page where you have this problem, or paste all of your javascript here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't add anything to the URL in your example, the browser assumes it's a relative URL and prefixes it with the current location origin (http://www.x-rayqa.co.uk on your site).  If that stored link is on the same server, you'll need to ensure the path is correct after the server name.

If it's not local (i.e., an external link) then you'll have to add the server and protocol prefix yourself to make the link work.  Take a look at the window.location documentation as well, which might help clear some things up.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

You can assign directly to `window.location.href` or use `window.location.assign()`.

Comment: Hi, the path is correct, the issue is that it adds the " marks to either side or the retrieved url so the full link with the added site address it doesn't work.  It is local

Comment: Ok, then a couple things to double check:

1. Is the link stored with '"'s per chance?
2. if you console.log(last_viewed), does it show the value correctly?

You show both:

`location.href = last_viewed;`

and

`location.href = '"' + last_viewed + '"'a`

does the first one give you a URL with quotes? If so, the quotes are most likely stored as part of the link in the database you are retrieving from.