# pass value to php script using location.href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When the user clicks the logout button a php script is called by a js call which closes the session and sends then to the home page.  I am trying to pass the url of the current page and store it in the database so when they log on again it takes them to the last page they viewed but I am unable to pass a value to the php script.

The js

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#logout_btn').click(function(){  
      $.msgbox("Are you sure you want to log out?", {  
        type: "confirm", 
        buttons: [
          {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
          {type: "cancel", value: "No"}
        ]
      }, function(result) {

        if (result == 'Yes') {
           var last_viewed = 'jim';
                 location.href = "logout.php?last_viewed="+last_viewed;
               }//close if yes 
            });//close function(result)
       });//close trigger
  });//close whole function
```

logout.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$last_viewed = $_GET['last_viewed'];

include 'includes/db_connect.php';

$sql = "UPDATE user SET last_view = '$last_viewed' WHERE userID = '$user_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

session_destroy();
header("location:index.php");
exit();
```

Logout script as it works except it doesn't get the value `last_viewed` from the js file so no value is entered into the db.  If I enter a literal value in `$last_viewed' the value is entered correctly.

Obviously 'jim' is not the actual url, I'm just using that for testing at the mo.

Comment: comment out `header("location:index.php");` and see the mysql_error()

Comment: @JasonOOO there is no error, just a blank page

Comment: If if remove the redirection and try to echo $last_viewed it is empty

Comment: You need to encode the `last_viewed` URL before sending it to the server.

Comment: @xFortyFourx - That's good practice, but in the example it's just the string `jim`, which shouldn't need URL encoding.

Comment: It should be noted that the posted code is just one huge SQL injection waiting to happen.

Comment: @adeneo what does that mean and why?

Comment: @adeneo haha yep, +1 for injection. Silly PHP. Also OP, 
`});//close function(result)` I don't think you need that `);` there, syntax error.

Comment: @xFortyFourx the script works despite the fact the value doesn't get passed,if I remove the bit you say shouldn't be there the whole thing doesn't work

Comment: @tatty27 I think you removed the `}` too, you are supposed to remove `);` only.

Comment: makes no difference to the functionality apart from the fact the dreamweaver flags it as a syntax error without the ); in place

Comment: @CBroe how can you say that I haven't made any attempts to narrow the problem?  If that was the case how would I know that it works if I pass a literal value rather than trying to get a value via the url?  I have been working at this for two hours before I posted on here!  The fact that even after 43 minutes of other people looking at it without coming up with  solution demonstrates that it isn't just a case of me being lazy.  And I guess you're the person who downvoted the question too?

Comment: _“The fact that even after 43 minutes of other people looking at it without coming up with solution demonstrates that it isn't just a case of me being lazy.”_ – no, it rather demonstrates that you have not provided enough useful information … And even after I asked some specific questions to try and narrow the issue down – no response to that either.

Comment: And also, this seems a duplicate of your own question just four hours earlier, [JQuery use value for location.href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455895/jquery-use-value-for-location-href)

Comment: They are completely different questions, one is asking why a value isn't being passed, one is about trying to get a value from a database formatted correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the line

`$last_viewed = $_GET['last_viewed'];`

so it was below

`include 'includes/db_connect.php';`

Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out:

```
location.href = "logout.php?last_viewed="+encodeURIComponent(last_viewed);
```

Comment: the value $last_viewed value is still empty

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: it is an empty array Array()

Comment: Just tested `location.href` with a PHP script and it works correctly. Maybe you should check your entire code for some bugs

Comment: I have posted my entire code, everything works except passing the value

Comment: no, the page goes to the correct url but the value isn't passed whether is use the above version or location.href = "logout.php?last_viewed=jim";  The php works if I enter a $last_value = 'jim'; rather than use $_GET

Comment: @tatty27 I think he asked, does it work if you enter the URL directly, `http://localhost/logout.php?last_viewed=jim`.

Comment: it says in my response to his question I used that

Comment: doesn't matter now any because I used php to retrieve the value of the url of the referring page rather than pass the value via javascript

Comment: If by that you mean that you rely on the HTTP Referer – that is not a solution at all, because clients are not required to send you that value, so it will fail in a lot of cases.

Comment: I have changed it so it doesn't use HTTP Referer now that I have worked out what he issue was